# How to instantiate a bean during the CDI AfterDeploymentValidation lifecycle event and pass a parameter to the bean?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

I'm working on a CDI extension which needs populate a `HashMap` with all the discovered beans that have a specific annotation and then during the `AfterDeploymentValidation` lifecyle event instantiate an `@ApplicationScoped` bean and pass the `HashMap` to the newly instantiated bean.

Using the following code I can find any beans that have been annotated with `@CQRSCommandHandler` and populate a `HashMap` with the name of the bean and parameter set on the annotation.

```
public class CQRSExtension implements Extension {

    private Map<String, String> discoveredCommandHandlers = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public <T> void processAnnotatedType(@Observes @WithAnnotations({ CQRSCommandHandler.class }) ProcessAnnotatedType<T> processAnnotatedType) {

        AnnotatedType<T> annotatedType = processAnnotatedType.getAnnotatedType();

        String commandName = annotatedType.getAnnotation(CQRSCommandHandler.class).command().getName();
        String handlerName = annotatedType.getJavaClass().getName();

        discoveredCommandHandlers.put(commandName, handlerName);

    }
}
```

What I'm struggling with is how I should eagerly instantiate the bean and pass the `HashMap` to this bean.

I can find plenty of examples such as this one (http://ovaraksin.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/eager-cdi-beans.html) that show how to eagerly instantiate any beans that have a specific annotation, however I cannot work out how to instantiate one specific bean and pass a `HashMap` to this bean.

Ideally I would prefer not to use reflections to scan for the annotation.

How can I instantiate one specific bean and pass a `HashMap` to this bean? Alternatively this there a better way to achieve the same result without using reflections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to eagerly instantiate the bean?

You have two options:

1. Inject the extension into the bean instead, and use the `HashMap` in there.

E.g.

```
@Inject
public MyAppScopedBean(MyExtension extension) {
    this.someHashMap = extension.getHashMap();
}
```

2. Pass the `HashMap` into a producer method to provide injection support for the `HashMap`.

You're essentially trying to break the concept of DI if you really want to instantiate the bean yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If runtime scanning is an alternative, you might want to take a look at https://code.google.com/p/reflections/ 
It provides an easy and powerful API.

Otherwise take a look at this link. The example in 16.10 is very similar, since in the example values in beans are set by the extension. You could adapt the example to set the hashMap into your application scoped bean. You would the simply use an observer method like this

```
  ApplicationScopedBean void processInjectionTarget(
        @Observes ProcessInjectionTarget<ApplicationScopedBean> pit) { ...
```

and set the map into the bean in your wrapped InjectionTaget implementation.

https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#_wrapping_an_literal_injectiontarget_literal